# How do I install dependencies for commerce using the Composer manager module

Tags: commerce, 8, composer

I installed the composer manager module and enabled it. I have tried initializing it from using drush in the command line and failed using the command `drush composer-manager-init`.

I am confused on how to add the libraries intl, address, pricing and tax to my site.

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to our installation instructions for Commerce 2.x here:

http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started.html

Note that we recommend the Drupal console project, not drush. However, the linked Composer Manager instructions in there may help you do it via drush.

Comment: http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/ Humbly correct the link that the god of drupal commerce @Ryan Szarama posted. I do not know why your link does not work.

Comment: hah, thanks. Looks like some URLs changed in a push to the gitbook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use drush to initialize composer manager. I usually use the init script from composer manager and have had no issue with it:

This is how I typically do it.

`php modules/composer_manager/scripts/init.php` (initialize composer manager)
`composer drupal-update --no-dev` (fetch dependencies)

You can also run  `composer drupal-update` without the `--no-dev` but I've found that composer sometimes can fail to update certain libraries within drupal core, as it expects to find .git files but these are not included in Drupal core builds.

Comment: So you mean i should run the scripts via the windows command line. thanks

Comment: This is the method I used.